# Can i print text and BarCode in one line Using Bixolon printer

Tags: android

I want to print something like this in one line using Bixolon's printer .
like : " Sale ||||||||||||||| " in one line. am using this code but its printing sale and barCode in separate line.

```
mBixolonPrinter.printText("Sale", alignment, attribute, 8, false);
mBixolonPrinter.print1dBarcode(barCode, barCodeSystem, 1, 2, 32, 0, true);
```

Comment: you can make a horizontal layout which have text and barcode view in one line. if you have barcode view seprately or a view in which you are adding this barcode

Comment: I want to print this using Bixolon's Printer.